# Google Maps direction request without traffic

Tags: php, json, maps, google-directions-api

I have to write a program, that tells me the shortest way between two points. The traffic shouldn't be regarded.

My Request is this.

```
'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin='.$from.'&destination='.$to.'&alternatives=true&sensor=false'
```

Then I take the shortest route this way

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url))->routes;
usort($data,create_function('$a,$b','return intval($a->legs[0]->distance->value) - intval($b->legs[0]->distance->value);'));
return floatval($data[0]->legs[0]->distance->text);
```

But this result depends to the actual traffic. 
How can I send a request, that ignores the actual traffic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using the [Distance Matrix Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix)?

Considering the API documentation, this should be what you're looking for:

> Google's Distance Matrix service computes travel distance and journey duration between multiple origins and destinations using a given mode of travel.
>
> This service does not return detailed route information.

Traffic situations should be ignored using this service.